# storing a project folder in isolated storage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am creating a windows phone project with static html files in a folder called "webapplication". i want to store all contents of "webapplication" folder in the isolated storage. Can some one help to resolve this?

Comment: this website is based on mutual respect and feedback! I see you are a new user, but if the solution was helpful, you should respond to it and appreciate the person who bothered to take out time and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out windows phone geek at http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-files-and-folders for information on Isolated Storage.

To create a folder do the following:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); 
myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("NewFolder");
```

If you want to create a file inside the folder then:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("NewFolder\\SomeFile.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, myIsolatedStorage));
```

If you are looking to copy the files to IsolatedStorage, then you need to run the following code the 1st time your application executes:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string[] files =  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
                foreach (var _fileName in files)
                {
                    if (!storage.FileExists(_fileName))
                    {
                        string _filePath = _fileName;
                        StreamResourceInfo resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(_filePath, UriKind.Relative));
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = storage.CreateFile("NewFolder\\SomeFile.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, Storage))
                        {
                            int chunkSize = 102400;
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
                            int byteCount;

                            while ((byteCount = resource.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
                            {
                                file.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply, the above answer doesnot serve my need. i want to loop through the file which are placed in the visual studio project directory of windows phone

Comment: If you have the folder path (webapplication?) then you can use  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string path) to get all the files in that folder. Then you can use the same method above to copy each of those files. I have modified the answer to include this suggestion